# youtube url won't open

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this code to open youtube url in youtube app if it is present otherwise in the safari browser but nothing is working

here is the code:

```
func openVideo(videoLink: String){
    print(videoLink)// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66q2fmLWMCI
    print(videoLink.replacingOccurrences(of: "https", with: "youtube")) // youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66q2fmLWMCI
    let url = URL(string: videoLink.replacingOccurrences(of: "https", with: "youtube"))
    if !UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!)  {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url!)
    }else{
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: videoLink)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
// I have also used 
// UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: videoLink)!)
// UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: videoLink)!)
    }
}
```

It gives me this error 
failed for URL: "youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66q2fmLWMCI" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an error just a log that the url cannot be opened in youtube, maybe because youtube is not installed on the device. 
Also you are opening youtube in wrong if else block. Youtube should be opened when you have a youtube app and not when you don't have which is what you are doing in your code. 
Just modify this line

```
    if !UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!)  {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: videoLink)!)
    }else{
        UIApplication.shared.open(url!)
    }
```